# Module index page redirection not working in YII

Tags: yii, url-routing

i am new user to yii framewrok.i added one new module in the name coupon for admin side(in admin folder) in YII framework. the default index page is loading fine which is in the path of `app/desig/admin/default/site/home.php`

but when i try to access `app/desig/admin/default/coupon/index.php` . it wont redirect to that page. empty white page is loaded.

what is the issue?. how can i solve this?.

Comment: What's the root directory of your app? Please do not post absolute filesystem paths if they are not relevant.

Comment: A completely empty white page may be a sign of a PHP syntax error or some other fatal error. Check the web server error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify the `coupon` module in the `modules` field of the configuration array in config/main.php? And did you import the model classes in the `import` field? Doing both of these should make it work.